# EntityFramework ChangeTracker together with MySql transaction

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, transactions

I'm just getting into Entity Framework, and I've been looking through the documentation so that I can gain a basic understanding.

All of MS' examples of saving data to the database use the context's ChangeTracker in a manner similar to how transactions are used in regular SQL (execute all the queries you want, then apply them all at once by calling `context.SaveChanges()`).

Example from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/basic):

```
using (var db = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blog = new Blog { Url = "http://sample.com" };
    db.Blogs.Add(blog);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is all well and good. However, looking at the documentation for the [MySql Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-introduction.html), in the examples for EF6 support, they use both the ChangeTracker *and* regular transactions.

Example from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html):

```
MySqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
try
{
    using (Parking context = new Parking(connection, false))
    {
        context.Database.UseTransaction(transaction);

        List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
        cars.Add(new Car { Manufacturer = "Nissan", Model = "370Z", Year = 2012 });    
        cars.Add(new Car { Manufacturer = "Ford", Model = "Mustang", Year = 2013 });
        cars.Add(new Car { Manufacturer = "Chevrolet", Model = "Camaro", Year = 2012 });
        cars.Add(new Car { Manufacturer = "Dodge", Model = "Charger", Year = 2013 });

        context.Cars.AddRange(cars);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    transaction.Commit();
}
catch
{
    transaction.Rollback();
    throw;
}
```

My question is, why use both? Are there any benefits to using transactions in this scenario? If so, are they specific to MySql, or is this true for all providers?

And to be clear, I realize that using the transaction allows rolling back all changes that were made in case of an exception, but doesn't disposing of the context without committing accomplish the same?

Comment: Maybe they just show you how to pass already existing transaction to EF context, who knows. Anyway that is indeed not necessary in regular usage.

Comment: Not sure about MySQL, but perhaps it's not using implicit transactions so if the first 2 car entities are inserted but the 3rd fails, what would you expect the database state to be in?

Comment: @DavidG I think `SaveChanges` is part of EF itself, not specific provider. And it will always start new transaction before applying changes.

Comment: @Evk Yes, it is.

Comment: @DavidG I would expect it to be in the state it was in before the first two, since the exception halts execution, so the commit is never reached, and the context is disposed.